# My VirtualBox Virtual Machine doesn't detect my USB attached disk

Tags: centos, virtualbox, windows, virtual-machine, usb-drive

I'm using the latest version of both Virtual Box (4.1) and CentOS (6.2). I would like my Western Digital USB drive to be recognized by my VirtualBox guest operating system.

My host system, Windows 7, recognizes it. It is also recognized when I open the settings of my VM. I've checked both `Enable USB Controller` and `Enable USB 2.0 Controller` and I've installed the Extension Pack for Virtual Box.

But when I launch the VM the USB devices icon in the right bottom corner shows "*No USB Devices attached*" and, of course, no USB drives are detected by CentOS.

Comment: Does `grep usbfs /etc/fstab` or `mount | grep usb` return anything?

Comment: I've just tried, It seems to work but doesnt return anything no ..

Comment: Haven't got the time right now, but try googling for `usbfs`, CentOS and VirtualBox... ([maybe this?](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2009-December/086970.html), without the remount)

Comment: @MilesM. can you post it as answer to your own question? How did you know which type of usb-port it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer :

It was because i've plugged my usb 3.0 usb drive on a 3.0 port, and that was he probem, VirtualBox doesn t seem to recognize 3.0 usb drives. but when I put it on a 2.0 usb drive, It works !